# Transaction does not roll back using TransactionTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-transactions

I am trying to handle transaction management using ***TransactionTemplate***. In this code, I left a line of code on purpose just to make sure that transaction rolls back when an exception occurs. But the transaction does not roll back. Here is the code.

```
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult(){

        protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status)
        {
            try 
            { 
                String SQL1 = "INSERT INTO Students (name, age) VALUES (?, ?)"; 
                jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL1, name, age); 

                String SQL2 = "SELECT MAX(id) from Students"; 
                int sid = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForInt( SQL2 ); 

                String SQL3 = "INSERT INTO Marks(StudentId, marks, year) " + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)"; 
                jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL3, sid, marks, year); 
                System.out.println("Created Name = " + name + ", Age = " + age); 

                transactionManager.commit(status);  // THIS IS THE LINE THAT CAUSES EXCEPTION. TRANSACTION DOES NOT ROLL BACK. 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                System.out.println("Error in creating record, rolling back"); 
                status.setRollbackOnly();
                //throw e; 
            } 
        }           
    });
```

Following exception is shown when **transactionManager.commit(status)** is encountered.

`Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: Transaction is already completed - do not call commit or rollback more than once per transaction`

Transaction commits successfully but does not roll back on exception. What could be wrong??

**========== EDIT ============**

I raised an exception using JdbcTemplate and it works absolutely fine. It commits and rolls back successfully.

Comment: Why are you even calling commit... What happens now is that a commit is already been done and spring tries to commit again (that is what the `TransactionTemplate` already does. So there is no way that something that  is already committed is going to be rolled back. Basically your analysis of the issue is off. You are using a `TransactionTemplate` then let that handle the transaction.

Comment: Yes. I understand what you said. It works fine if this is commented. But this is still AN EXCEPTION. And it should be rolling back. Is my understanding wrong somewhere ??

Comment: No it shouldn't rollback... The data is already committed due to your manual commit. There is no way you can rollback already committed data. It will be rolled back if you simply throw a runtime exception instead of calling commit. The issue is you are abusing a commit to have the second commit fail.

Answer (score 2):

What happens in your code example is:

- `transactionManager.commit(status);` causes the transaction to commit
- no exception is raised in the `doInTransactionWithoutResult()` callback, so `TransactionTemplate` tries to commit the transaction
- since the transaction was already commited by your code, the commit fails, causing the `IllegalTransactionStateException` to be thrown from `TransactionTemplate` (library code, not yours)